# codeigniter view will not load after form submission

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2

I have a weird error, unless I'm missing something:

I am trying to work with https://github.com/jackilyn/bootstrap-contact/ to add a bootstrap contact form to my codeigniter project.

The form is submitted as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php/my_controller/my_contact_form_handler" id="contactform">
```

in the my_controller class I have:

```
public function contact_form_handler() 
{
     $this->load->view('sub_directory/contact_form');  
    // reload contact form it just came from
    echo 'hello';
    exit;
}
```

The output is 'hello'. Why won't this view load ( PS I've also tried other views in the same spot. they won't display either! )

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `exit;` line.
Your view hasn't yet been rendered at that point.